# How to iterate a sObject in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

im new to salesforce

I have a sObject (A__c) with a lookup relationship with B__c and C__c.

I would like to have a table for each A that displays his related B and C

example:

A

---

B        C

How can i do that?
i have done this apex code:

```java
public with sharing class reportExtension {
    public A__c efv;
    private reportExtension keListFinal;

    public reportExtension(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
        List<A__c> singleKey = new List<A__c> ();
        List<A__c> efi= [SELECT B__r.Name FROM A__c];

        for(A__c efv : efi) {
            singleKey.add([SELECT B__r.Description__c , C__r FROM A__c]);
        }
    }
}
```

and then i have this visualforce:

```html
<apex:page standardController="A__c" extensions="reportPdfExtension">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="title" id="title">
            <!-- Contacts List -->
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!A__c}" var="cki">
                    <apex:column value="{!cki.Name}"/>
 ..... ??
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: standardControllers are used when the target is a single object record and typically invoked from a button on the object detail page; as the answer given shows, since you are displaying all records from A__c, you would use either a standardSetController or a custom controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I do not think that you need to use** `standardController` here.
The **simple solution** for your case. (*Of course you can modify it with some styles for your needs.* )

The Apex Class :

```
public class ReportExtension {

    public List<A__c> recordsList{get;set;}

    public reportExtension() {
        recordsList = [SELECT Name, B__r.Name, C__r.Name FROM A__c];
    }
}
```

And the Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page controller="ReportExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:repeat value="{!recordsList}" var="record">
            <table >
                <tr colspan="1">
                    <td>{! record.Name }</td>
                </tr>
                <tr colspan="2">
                    <td>{! record.B__r.Name }</td>
                    <td>{! record.C__r.Name }</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Note :

**Do not use SELECT query in loops** (It is a really **bad practice** and can cause **the Limit exception** )

Comment: even simpler is to move the SOQL into the getter and out of the constructor. That said, this really calls for a standardSetController with pagination as ViewState could easily blow up

Comment: @Vitalii thank you for putting effort in this.

the purpose of what i have to do is: 

I have a school report (A__c) for each student and for

Each school report have a subject (B__c) and some micro arguments (C__r.Name) 

I want print the school report of a children of my choice, with all his subjects, related micro arguments